# Why Laravel pagination show same page?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a blog module in my laravel with multiple categories.In other categories pagination works just fine but with this category method links() always show the first page.This is my code:

```
  $page = Categoriepage::where('identifiant', 'orientation')->first();

    $idArticle = Articleliaison::select(array('idArticle'))->where('idPage',$page->id)->pluck('idArticle');

    $articles = Article::whereIn('id',$idArticle)->where('status','enable')->orderby('created_at','desc')->get()->take(6);

    $links = Article::whereIn('id',$idArticle)->where('status','enable')->orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);

    return View::make('pages.orientation')->with('articles',$articles)->with('links',$links);
```

and in my view:

```
  <?php $i = 1 ?>

                <div class="masonry ">

                @foreach($articles as $article)

                    @include('components.article-or')

                <?php $i++ ?>

                @endforeach()

                </div>


                <div class="text-center" style="margin-top: 5%">

                    {{ $links->links() }}

                </div>
```

Comment: `{{ $links->links() }}` this should be `{{ $articles->links() }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always select the first 6 articles because the articles displayed come from:

```php
$articles = Article::whereIn('id',$idArticle)->where('status','enable')->orderby('created_at','desc')->get()->take(6);
```

and not from a paginate request.

There is no need to separate the query for the links and the query for the actual articles. Instead of:

```php
$articles = Article::whereIn('id',$idArticle)->where('status','enable')->orderby('created_at','desc')->get()->take(6);
$links = Article::whereIn('id',$idArticle)->where('status','enable')->orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
```

You can do:

```php
$articles = Article::whereIn('id',$idArticle)->where('status','enable')->orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);
```

and in your view:

```
<div class="masonry ">
   @foreach($articles as $article)
     @include('components.article-or')
    @endforeach
</div>

<div class="text-center" style="margin-top: 5%">
  {{ $articles->links() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you got this one a bit mixed up.

You retrieve all articles (`->get()`) and take the first six (`->take(6)`). And then you retrieve `$links` using `->paginator(6)`.

This can and should all be done using just the `->paginator(6)`, this way Laravel retrieves the correct `6` articles for the `?page=X` you are on and renders the links based on the total amount of articles found by the query.

Try it like this:

```php
$page = Categoriepage::where('identifiant', 'orientation')->first();

$idArticle = Articleliaison::select(array('idArticle'))->where('idPage',$page->id)->pluck('idArticle');

$articles = Article::whereIn('id',$idArticle)->where('status','enable')->orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);

return View::make('pages.orientation')->with('articles',$articles)
```

```
                <?php $i = 1 ?>

                <div class="masonry ">
                    @foreach($articles as $article)
                        @include('components.article-or')

                        <?php $i++ ?>
                    @endforeach
                </div>

                <div class="text-center" style="margin-top: 5%">
                    {{ $articles->links() }}
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you do not have to make two requests but only one

```
 $page = Categoriepage::where('identifiant', 'orientation')->first();

$idArticle = Articleliaison::select(array('idArticle'))->where('idPage',$page->id)->pluck('idArticle');

$articles = Article::whereIn('id',$idArticle)->where('status','enable')->orderby('created_at','desc')->paginate(6);


return View::make('pages.orientation')->with('articles',$articles);
```

In your view.

```
             <div class="masonry ">

            @foreach($articles as $article)

                @include('components.article-or')

            <?php $i++ ?>

            @endforeach()

            </div>


            <div class="text-center" style="margin-top: 5%">

                {{ $articles->links() }}

            </div>
```